# Unmatched } in PHP / Wordpress, but I have no unmatched } in my opionion?

Tags: php, wordpress, post

I have an issue which I can't seem to solve. Suddenly I get an error message Unmatched } in PHP. But I have not changed the code itself and after checking, I can't find why a } would be unmatched. There's not to many or missing either.

I have tried adding / removing } but this does not work. Maybe this has to do with custom posts or change in PHP, but I can't find what this might be.

```
<div class="right">

<?php $relatedProjects = get_field('related_projects');

if ($relatedProjects) { 
  
  ?>

<h3>Gerelateerde <span>werken.</span></h3>

 <div class="wrap">

<? foreach ($relatedProjects as $relatedProject) { ?>

   <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($relatedProject); ?>" class="item">
     <div class="image">
      <?php 
      $related_id = $relatedProject->ID;
      
      echo get_the_post_thumbnail($related_id, 'medium' );  
      
      ?>
       <div class="subtitle"><?php echo get_the_title($relatedProject);?>
       </div>
     </div>
   </a>

  <?php } 

} ?>

 </div>
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? That's so little code that it should not be too hard to spot the line that causes the problem. Also, doesn't the error message contain more details?

Comment: The last `}` is unmatched, because no corresponding `{` was found. _Short open tags_ are a thing of the past - the parser does not recognize your line starting with `<? foreach` _as_ PHP code in the first place. You need to use `<?php foreach` there.

Comment: change <? foreach to <?php foreach

Answer (score 1):

I already found the solution: apparently PHP is more "strict" on my new server, which does not accept `<?` as an opening tag. Replacing it nicely with `<?php` was the solution.